# Ingress Controller using Fabric8's Java library

Tags: java, kubernetes, fabric8, kubernetes-ingress

I am looking for an example with the implementation of an Ingress Resource that can work with external controllers using Fabric8. I could not find it here https://github.com/fabric8io/ in any of the repositories

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /testpath
        backend:
          serviceName: test
          servicePort: 80
```

Is there an Ingress Builder?

Comment: What do you mean by "Is there an Ingress Builder"?

Comment: I can’t seem to find the relevant classes to build an Ingress Resource in the fabric8 repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using fluent DSL to build Ingress Resource from https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client

```
new IngressBuilder()
```

This is what you're looking for?

Comment: Hey Hrishikesh, Thanks but again , I can’t find it’s javadoc. Can you please link the class or the javadoc

Comment: We don't have javadoc. The assumption is fluent DSL builder is a known way to create/build resource.
Still, I take it as community feedback

Comment: is that the resource or the controller builder

Comment: Hi, is there a way to create an Ingress Object from the builder? Ingress ig = IngressBuilder.build() doesnt seem to work? I want to post the request to teh API to create an Ingress resource from the builder object?Using client.extentions().ingress()